# How can I show the differences beetween 2 columns from different tables using UTL_MATCH in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, string-comparison, case-when, utl-match

I have two columns In Oracle DB which I want to compare, and if the strings are different, I want to show the differences in other columns it. I know I miss something.
So for example:

```
SELECT A.CD_KEY01,
       A.TEXT_01,
       B.TEXT_02,
       UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(A.TEXT_01, B.TEXT_02) AS distance_similarity
FROM TB_TABLE_01 A 
JOIN TB_TABLE_02 B
ON A.CD_KEY01 = B.CD_KEY02
```

Example output I get:

```
CD_KEY01  |  TEXT_01              |  TEXT_02               | DISTANCE_SIMILARITY 
   111    |  Superman is good     |  Superman is good      | 100
   222    |  Superman is bad      |  Superman is bad       | 100
   333    |  Superman is handsome |  Hulk is ugly          | 33
   444    |  Superman is awful    |  Batman is awful       | 90
```

Example output I need:

```
CD_KEY01  |  TEXT_01              |  TEXT_02               | DISTANCE_SIMILARITY | DIFF_01 | DIFF_02 
   111    |  Superman is good     |  Superman is good      | 100                 | NULL    | NULL
   222    |  Superman is bad      |  Superman is bad       | 100                 | NULL    | NULL
   333    |  Superman is handsome |  Hulk is ugly          | 33                  | Hulk    | ugly
   444    |  Superman is awful    |  Batman is awful       | 90                  | Batman  | NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is an easy way. One method is to divide strings into words somehow (recursive way below), compare word by word and pivot result:

```
with 
  a(key, text_a, word, rn) as (
    select cd_key01, text_01, regexp_substr(text_01, '(\w+)', 1, 1), 1 
      from table_01 
    union all
    select key, text_a, regexp_substr(text_a, '(\w+)', 1, rn + 1), rn + 1 
      from a 
      where regexp_substr(text_a, '(\w+)', 1, rn + 1) is not null),
  b(key, text_b, word, rn) as (
    select cd_key02, text_02, regexp_substr(text_02, '(\w+)', 1, 1), 1 
      from table_02 
    union all
    select key, text_b, regexp_substr(text_b, '(\w+)', 1, rn + 1), rn + 1 
      from b where regexp_substr(text_b, '(\w+)', 1, rn + 1) is not null)
select *
  from (
    select key, rn, text_a, text_b, 
           case when a.word <> b.word then b.word end word 
      from a full join b using (key, rn))
  pivot (max(word) for rn in (1 w1, 2 w2, 3 w3)) order by key
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=865b65ae4fc8718a972117d6425e60f3)</sup>**

This query shows comparison for first three words, `is` is also compared. If strings may have different number of words you have to be carefull and modify `case when` part handling nulls properly.